XA0010: No se pudo recuperar la ABI de android para el dispositivo
Estoy conectando una tablet Samsung Galaxy Tab Active (SM-T360)(V. Android 5.1.1) a Visual Studio 2022 (17.10.0) como dispositivo local android para poder depurar mis apps en MAUI .NET.
Mi problema es que no me reconoce el dispositivo y me aparece como "Unknow" en el listado de "Dispositivos locales Android" y si intento lanzar la depuración me muestra el siguiente error:
XA0010: No se pudo recuperar la ABI de Android para el dispositivo o emulador adjunto “f03b316a0978ca35”. Vuelva a conectar el dispositivo o reinicie el emulador e inténtelo de nuevo.
Es el primer dispositivo android con el que me encuentro este problema y no se como solucionarlo.
¿Alguien se ha encontrado con un problema similar y ha podido solucionarlo?
PD: la tablet está configurada correctamente en modo desarrollador y windows la reconoce sin problemas.
Gracias. Un saludo.


